# Is it possible to create MAML only documentation

Tags: sandcastle, shfb, maml

I'm trying to create a help system that doesn't (necessarily) include any reflected code sections.  Using the latest Sandcastle Help File Builder, is it possible to only include MAML XML files, and is so what setting needs to be changed, because currently I get

Error BE0042: You must specify at least one documentation source in the form of an assembly or a Visual Studio solution/project file.

Answer (score 1):

That is very easy.
You only have to open the properties of the SHFB project and jump to the Plug-Ins tab. Here you only have to add "Additional Content Only".

Comment: Wow, thanks Ralf - 7 years later.  I haven't used Sandcastle for probably 6+ years...  But it's on my list of things to revisit...